# Is C[X,Y]/<XY> isomorphic to the product ring (C[X]/<X>)×(C[Y]/<Y>)

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, ideals, unique-factorization-domains

I need help with this. As  and  are not comaximal ideals I cant direct use the Chinese remainder theorem. Both fails to be integral domain. The right side ring is isomorphic to C×C. But I dont know how to get a difference between this rings. Please help!

Comment: Don't their $\mathbb{C}$-vector space dimensions differ?

Comment: The second ring has idempotents. Does the first ring have any?

Comment: 1+<XY> is an idempotent in the left side ring.

Comment: Ok I understand you are talking about nontrivial idempotents. Ok thank you so much. I can do this now.